# Font Color on PdfPCell increases the size of PDF file

Tags: itext, pdf-generation, openpdf

I have created a Font in this way.

```
Font tableHeaderFont = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.WHITE);
```

and then using it inside PdfPCell with Phrase.

```
PdfPCell hcell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Column A", tableHeaderFont));
```

I am showing table header on every page.

Now if I drop the Font Color, it generates the `PDF file of size 10 MB` but when Color is provided it generates PDF file of `size 24 MB`. There are around 1400 page in PDF document.

Is there any better way to specify Font Color on PdfPCell level?

In addition to this, when I try to merge these pdf documents using `PdfSmartCopy` it takes around 4 GB memory usage.

I have tried both `iText` & `OpenPDF`.

**Update:**

**iText 5.5:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

When I use the **BaseColor** class of iText 5+ then I am getting the same size of pdf file with or without Font Color.

```
Font tableHeaderFont = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.WHITE);
```

**OpenPDF 1.3.20**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.20</version>
</dependency>
```

But OpenPDF doesn't come with **BaseColor** class so I have to use **Color.WHITE** here.

```
Font tableHeaderFont = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.WHITE);
```

Do we have any alternative of **BaseColor** class in **OpenPDF** or **iText4**?

**Update 2: Sample Use Case to reproduce the issue.**

**OpenPDF Impl: PDF File Size is around 15 MB**

```
import com.lowagie.text.*;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class TestOpenPDF {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 10, 10, 10, 10);
        Document.compress = false;
        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                    new FileOutputStream("AddBigTable_OpenPDF.pdf"));
            document.open();
            String[] bogusData = {"M0065920"};
            int NumColumns = 1;

            PdfPTable datatable = new PdfPTable(NumColumns);
            datatable.getDefaultCell().setPadding(3);
            datatable.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidth(2);
            datatable.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(
                    Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            Font tableHeaderFont = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 20, Font.NORMAL, Color.WHITE);
            PdfPCell header = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Clock #", tableHeaderFont));
            header.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            header.setPadding(3);
            header.setBorderWidth(2);
            header.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            datatable.addCell(header);

            datatable.setHeaderRows(1); // this is the end of the table header

            datatable.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidth(1);
            for (int i = 1; i < 75000; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    datatable.getDefaultCell().setGrayFill(0.9f);
                }
                for (int x = 0; x < NumColumns; x++) {
                    datatable.addCell(bogusData[x]);
                }
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    datatable.getDefaultCell().setGrayFill(1);
                }
            }
            document.add(datatable);
        } catch (Exception de) {
            de.printStackTrace();
        }
        document.close();
    }
}
```

**iText Impl: PDF File Size is around 8.5 MB**

```
import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class TestIText {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 10, 10, 10, 10);
        Document.compress = false;
        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                    new FileOutputStream("AddBigTable_iText.pdf"));
            document.open();
            String[] bogusData = {"M0065920"};
            int NumColumns = 1;

            PdfPTable datatable = new PdfPTable(NumColumns);
            datatable.getDefaultCell().setPadding(3);
            datatable.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidth(2);
            datatable.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(
                    Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            Font tableHeaderFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 20, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.WHITE);
            PdfPCell header = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Clock #", tableHeaderFont));
            header.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            header.setPadding(3);
            header.setBorderWidth(2);
            header.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            datatable.addCell(header);

            datatable.setHeaderRows(1); // this is the end of the table header

            datatable.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidth(1);
            for (int i = 1; i < 75000; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    datatable.getDefaultCell().setGrayFill(0.9f);
                }
                for (int x = 0; x < NumColumns; x++) {
                    datatable.addCell(bogusData[x]);
                }
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    datatable.getDefaultCell().setGrayFill(1);
                }
            }
            document.add(datatable);
        } catch (Exception de) {
            de.printStackTrace();
        }
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed with latest version of **OpenPDF 1.3.25**. I was using the older version.

Answer (score 1):

From the snippets which are shared, I can grasp that `iText 2` is used. If it is possible, it is better to reconsider such a choice, since `iText 2` is more than 10 years old, potentially has a lot of functional and security issues and no longer maintained.

I recommend updating to `iText 7`. Although I do not have your code and thus could not prove that in your case setting color would not make the size of the PDF much bigger, I have created the following sample to demonstrate that there should no issue:

```
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        doc.add(new Paragraph("Hello World")/*.setFontColor(ColorConstants.RED)*/);
    }

    doc.close();
```

The size of the resultant PDF, in which font color is enabled, is 161Kb; the size of the resultant PDF, in which font color is disabled, is 160Kb (that is fully expected, because enabling a color means writing the corresponding instruction to the PDF: there are 10k instructions there, hence 1Kb difference).

Comment: Yes I am using OpenPDF (iText4). I have the same observation when using iText 5+. Font tableHeaderFont = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.WHITE); There is not much difference in PDF file size when I use BaseColor.

Comment: @java_maestros you mean BaseFont.Helvetica? Could you add a simplified sample which shows the issue, so that one could run it and play with it?

Comment: No I mean to say BaseColor.WHITE. I have updated the question. I can only use iText4 (not higher version) or OpenPDF.

Comment: @@Uladzimir Asipchuk I have added the sample which shows the isue.